# Unable to include rapidjson library in VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, rapidjson

I am trying to include the `rapidjson` library in my VS community 2017 project.

On creating a new project, I tried including/adding the directory `rapidjson-master\include\rapidjson`at the following places :

1. Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.
2. Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories.

Either way, when I try to include a `rapidjson` related file, VS tells me that it cannot find the source file.

So, when i give this :

```
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
```

I get the following errors :

> Error (active)    E1696   cannot open source file "rapidjson/document.h"
>
> Error (active)    E1696   cannot open source file "rapidjson/writer.h"
>
> Error (active)    E1696   cannot open source file "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"

**VS Info :**

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017
>
> Version 15.6.3

Let me know if you know the right way to use `rapidjson` in Visual Studio.

**EDIT :**

The [rapidjson documentation](http://rapidjson.org/) advises us to *"just copy the `include/rapidjson` folder to system or project's include path"*.

Comment: Does `rapidjson-master\include\rapidjson` have `document.h` in it?  If it does I believe the include directory should be `rapidjson-master\include`

Comment: `document.h` is indeed in `\include\rapidjson`.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the others are also present in the aforementioned path.

Comment: @NathanOliver : Even on adding `rapidjson-master\include` to the include directory, I get the same problem.

Comment: Add just `rapidjson-master\include` to the include path.

Comment: @rustyx : as my earlier comment implies, I tried that as well. But it still can't seem to find my source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time trying to figure out why it wasn't including the external libraries, I finally found my solution.

When I was adding the path to my `additional include directories`, I was doing it under the following configuration :

> Configuration : Debug
>
> Platform : x64.

However, in my VS2017, every time I create a new project, the default configuration that is set for compilation/run is as follows :

> Configuration : Debug
>
> Platform : x86

The main reason behind my problem was the mismatch of platforms between configuring the project and compiling the project. So, I guess it's always better to check if the platform and configuration is the same in such cases.

**Additional Info : ( regarding the comments and the other answer to this question )**

It doesn't matter if the directory included is `rapidjson-master\include\rapidjson` or `rapidjson-master\include\`. In the former we include the files as `#include "document.h"` and in the latter it would be `#include "rapidjson/document.h"`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the include path should be just `rapidjson-master\include`, but let's start from the beginning.

1. Clone the rapidjson repository; do the following in a command window:

   ```
   mkdir C:/ThirdParty
   cd C:/ThirdParty
   git clone https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson.git
   ```

   Substitute a convenient directory for `C:/ThirdParty`.
2. In Visual Studio, open the solution and in Solution Explorer, select the project that is using rapidjson and either use the main menu PROJECT Properties function, or right-click on the project and select Properties from the option menu. This will display the Properties dialog.
3. Select C/C++ General in list on the left side of the dialog.
4. Now on the right side of the dialog, the first line should be "Additional Include Directories". Edit that line, adding `C:/ThirdParty/rapidjson/include`at the end of the list.

Comment: Appreciate the time taken to answer the question, but the problem turned out to be a rather careless mistake.

Answer (score 0):

For those that still have this problem, I realized after a while of debugging that the reason that the error occurs is because the file can't be found within the remote project directory - even if it exists and is included properly in your local Windows project.

In order for the remote project to compile properly with the 3rd party headers, they have to be copied over from your Windows directory.

I solved the problem like this:

- First, I added the rapidjson header files to my project in the **Solution Explorer** window. It seems that they have to be explicitly included there in order for Visual Studio to copy the files to your remote project directory. In order to maintain the directory structure of the rapidjson include directory, I added the headers in their appropriate "filters" (the folder icons) - see screenshot below (project name censored due to it being a company project):

[image: VS Solution Explorer rapidjson]

- Then, I changed how I wrote the #include statement from `#include "rapidjson\document.h"` to `"rapidjson/document.h"` (i.e. use the Linux file path syntax).
- Finally, I rebuilt the project. It successfully copied the header files to the remote project and my source files can "find" them now.